# wp_localize_script Function not Working: Followed Similar Questions Solutions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In functions.php I have put as below:

```
    function wp12311_enqueue_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'wp12311-scripts',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/test/scripts-test.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
     wp_localize_script( 'wp12311-scripts', 'userDetails', array(
         'current_user' => wp_get_current_user()
     ) ) ;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp12311_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then, in /test/scripts-test.js I have below code:

```
    var userEmail = userDetails.current_user.username.data.user_email;
console.log("display is " + userEmail);
```

In my HTML file I have below code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/scripts-test.js"></script>

    <title>Test</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />



  </head>

  <body>

</body>


</html>
```

When I load the html file, I get the error:

```
scripts-test.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: userDetails is not defined
```

Please let know what is the issue and how can I make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it too early, try to wait until document is ready. and it's better to use the global window object

```
jQuery(document).on( 'ready', function() {
    var userEmail = window.userDetails.current_user.username.data.user_email;
    console.log("display is " + userEmail);
});
```